# Using variables in imap_search() criteria

Tags: php, gmail, imap

Sorry, I'm probably missing something simple here, but I feel like I've tried everything. I'm a PHP beginner, so that likely explains it.

Okay, so I am having emails sent to an inbox with a key appended to the mailbox. For example:

jerry+examplekey@gmail.com

I'm trying to create a loop that does something to all emails with that key attached to it.

When I do

```
foreach ($valid_keys as $key){ // granted this loop does nothing for now
if ($emails = imap_search($mbox, 'To "examplekey"')){echo "Found emails.";};
}
```

It works absolutely fine. That is, when I specify the "To" criteria string manually.
But when I try to put a variable in to the To criteria instead of a string, it doesn't find it--even when I've verified that $key is equal to a key that's in the inbox (I was echoing it in the loop to make sure).

```
foreach ($valid_keys as $key){
if ($emails = imap_search($mbox, 'To "$key"')){echo "found one";}; // this doesn't work
}
```

I've tried wrapping it in curly braces, fiddling with the quotes, putting the whole 'To "$key"' criteria in a $string and then doing it like imap_search($mbox, $string) and it doesn't work.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `'To "$key"'` to `"To \"$key\""`

PHP only does variable substitution in double quotes `""`

Single quotes are faster because of this, PHP doesn't have to search through the string to find variables.

So you could also do it using the concatenation operator like this `'To "'.$key.'"'`

Comment: Thank you! Using double quotes on the criteria and escaping the quotes on the $key worked. I knew it was something simple